# Updating Opendaylight Unimgr Feature

Tags: maven, opendaylight

I am adding a new driver to Opendaylight's unimgr, and I added a new feature to the controller to allow use of this driver.

It works fine, but when I make changes to my driver and rebuild it (`mvn clean install -pl my-new-driver -DskipTests`), after running `feature:install odl-unimgr-my-new-driver`, I still get the old version (even if I clear the data folder beforehand, or perform `bundle:update` and `bundle:refresh`).

Is there a way to update the feature without building the entire unimgr (and hence the entire controller) again?

Some information about my setup: I use SNAPSHOT versions, and am running the karaf which is built as part of the unimgr project (`unimgr/karaf/target/assembly/bin/karaf`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to the fact that the local project karaf distros copy all the artifacts under *target/assembly/system* and the target/assembly/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file is set up to only look under system. So to get updates, you can either

- rebuild the distro in *unimgr/karaf*
- copy the updated artifact to the appropriate directory under *target/assembly/system* and then re-install the feature
- set **org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository=** in *etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg* so it will look in your ~/.m2/repository. Then after re-building the artifact you just need to re-install the feature

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really work for me. Your first suggestion is what I'm trying to avoid; the second partially works (the new feature is loaded) but exceptions are thrown (like "Unable to provide source for..."), ans that doesn't happen when I rebuild everything; as for the third - when attempting to reinstall the feature it fails because of unresolved dependencies.

Comment: I don't know what "Unable to provide source for..." error means - would need to see the full error and trace.  For 2 & 3, by reinstall the feature I mean stop karaf, then rebuild the artifact, for 2 copy the updated artifact, then delete the data directory to clear all the cached bundles, then restart karaf (did you do these steps?). Then do feature:install or add the feature to the featuresBoot in etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg so it's installed automatically on startup.

Comment: I forgot to mention, for 3, I believe you need to also delete system/org/opendaylight/* so it finds all ODL artifacts in ~/.m2/repository.  I typically don't use the project-specific distros - I have my own local karaf install that I deploy features into via featuresBoot and  where I've set up org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg to look in ~/.m2/repository. When I need to re-deploy updates, I stop karaf, rebuild the artifact, delete data/* and restart karaf.

Comment: For the second method I did all but remove the data directory. After doing that - it works perfectly. Thank you for the help!